# Silverlight asp.net WCF authentication 2.0

Tags: .net, wcf, silverlight, configuration, wcf-security

Can anyone provide some links to *good* information on setting up Silverlight 2.0 to authenticate to a WCF Service through ASP.NET Forms Authentication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this link could help you 
http://silverlightuk.blogspot.com/2008/03/silverlight-wcf-and-aspnet.html

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good place to get started.  The technology that allows you to use ASP.NET Forms Auth in SL2 is called ASP.NET Application Services - it's easy to use.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838250(VS.95).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Kevin Rohling put together a great walk through for doing ws-security with SL 2 a little while back. You could probably plug your logic into the hooks in his example. Check it out here: [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20200815091929/http://geekswithblogs.net/SunnyCoder/archive/2009/03/15/username-password-amp-ws-security-with-silverlight.aspx)

Cheers